# Failed to run the DB2 command using jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

Trying to run the db2 command using jdbc. Below is java code and exception

**db2 load from file of del modified by coldel0x09 insert into item**
Code:

```
           Connection conn = getConnectionFromDB(); // Connection object
           Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(); //Statement object
           sql = "db2 load from filepath of del modified by coldel0x09 insert into tablename";//command
           System.out.println("Executing command: "+ sql);
           stmt.execute(sql);
       } catch (SQLException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException("Error loading into table '" + tableName + "' with SQL: " + sql, e);
       }
   }
```

getting Exception after run the command:

> Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error:
>   SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=load;db2 ;JOIN
>   , DRIVER=4.9.78
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:676)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:60)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:127)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.en.c(en.java:2553)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.en.d(en.java:2541)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.en.b(en.java:1957)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.h(cb.java:221)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.b(cb.java:47)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.q.b(q.java:38)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.rb.h(rb.java:114)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.en.hb(en.java:1952)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.en.a(en.java:3040)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.en.e(en.java:1028)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.en.execute(en.java:1012)

Comment: Incorrect code. LOAD is a *command*  understood by the Db2-CLP, and so it is not SQL and therefore cannot be executed as SQL.   Lookup the stored procedure ADMIN_CMD , which lets you do a load for Db2-on-Linux/Unix/Windows only. See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0023577.html

Comment: Also consider using an `EXTERNAL TABLE` to load your data if you are using Db2 11.5.  This is an SQL statement and not a command like LOAD https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r_create_ext_table.html   it can also load remote files, again unlike LOAD

Answer (score 2):

[Error -104](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc-gentopic1.html#sql0104n) is a syntax error, "unexpected token". What you are trying to do is to execute a command line command within a JDBC environment. That does not work by design.

[You may want to look into executing LOAD by calling the ADMIN_CMD procedure](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0023577.html). [ADMIN_CMD](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/c0061222.html) allows to run administrative commands without having the command line interface available.

Comment: Read what I wrote. You can't use that command and have to switch using ADMIN_CMD. See the links

Answer (score 0):

As per [data_henkik comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59049211/10967262) your code should look like:

```
  String storedProcedure = "CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD('load from [insert full load command here]')";
  CallableStatement cstm = conn.prepareCall(storedProcedure);
  cstm.execute();
```