# db2 load command fails using JDBC

Tags: jdbc, db2, db2-luw

I'm using JDBC to transfer data from a delimited file to a db2 database table. Initially, I encountered SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, so on further debugging I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59048905/failed-to-run-the-db2-command-using-jdbc) which referred me to call stored procedure *SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD*.

I modified the call and tried running the procedure version, but I'm still getting the same error:

> com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=CLIENT;LOAD;FROM, DRIVER=4.26.14
> Error |
> at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b7.a(b7.java:810)
> Error |
> at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b7.a(b7.java:66)

I'm not sure what exactly am doing wrong.

Code:

```
CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD('LOAD CLIENT FROM "<PATH_TO_FILE>" OF DEL MODIFIED BY COLDEL0X09 INSERT INTO <SCHEMA_NAME>.<TABLE_NAME> NONRECOVERABLE')
```

I ran the LOAD command on the db2 command prompt and it ran without any issues.

Db2 version: 11.5

Comment: Remove the `CLIENT` keyword from the command.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein This works fine if db2 is on my local. What should be a way to load if the db2 is on remote machine?

Comment: This is a Stored Procedure invocation. SP runs on server, and as you could expect, it may have an access to a file on a remote machine, if it's accessible from the server only. You may try to load from a remote external table instead, if you are at V11.5.

Answer (score 1):

The `load client` command is intended for use at a client workstation, not at a Db2-server, so `sysproc.admin_cmd` will reject the client keyword.

The stored procedure executes at the Db2-server , it does not have access to files that are stored at the client workstation.

Therefore any file you mention in parameters to `sysproc.admin_cmd` stored procedure must be relative to the Db2-server file-system and must be accessible (readable) to the Db2-instance owner account.

If your data-file is already located on the Db2-server, just reference its fully qualified filename and run the `sysproc.admin_cmd` procedure with the `load` command.  Carefully check the documentation for the load command to understand all of the implications of using LOAD, especially if the target Db2-server is highly-available. This is an administration matter.

If your data-file is not already located at a Db2-server, then first copy the file to the Db2-server and retry with load (or slower `import`).

You can also run the `import` command via `sysproc.admin_cmd` when the data file is accessible to the Db2-instance owner on the Db2-server than runs that stored-procedure.

If your Db2-version is recent you can also consider the `ingest` command, refer to the documentation for details.

If your data file is located on a client workstation, and you are unable or unwilling to transfer it to a Db2-server, then you can use your local workstation Db2-client (if you installed a suitable Db2-client that includes the db2 CLP) to run a script/batch-file to perform the relevant commands. You cannot use jdbc for that specific purpose, although you can exec/shell out from java to run the required commands in one script (`db2 connect to ... user ...using ..`,   `db2 load client ...`  , or `db2 ingest ...` or `db2 import ...`

If your target Db2-server is already at version 11.5 or higher then it should support insert from external table, and remote external table, and since INSERT is plain SQL then you can do that via jdbc.

Apart from the above, most DBAs would arrange for direct Db2-server to Db2-server transfers if both are Db2-LUW and have IP-connectivity and if security rules permit, this avoids the slow and insecure business of taking the data outside of Db2. That is not a programming matter, more an administrative matter.

Comment: Thank you @mao for detailed answer. In my case, the file will be present at the client workstation. I don't think I can transfer it to the server. Is there any other alternative to perform data loading using JDBC?